# WPF Calendar loses blackout dates when enabled / disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a calendar control that I disable dates on using Blackout dates.  The calendar control is bound to another property that allows a user to enable or disable the calendar.

The Blackout dates work perfectly but, when a user enables / disables the calendar when it comes back all the blackout dates have disappeared - why is this happening or how can I stop it happening?

```
<Calendar IsEnabled="{Binding StartTheSceduleNow, Converter={StaticResource BoolToOppositeBoolConverter}}" x:Name="Calender" Loaded="CalendarLoaded"  >
```

Code behind the .cs

```
private void CalendarLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Calender.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)));
}
```

Comment: Okay. And what's your question?

Comment: Updated - why is it happening or how do I stop it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be something on your end. For me this XAML works together with your Loaded method:

```
<Grid>
  <StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="theBox" />
    <Calendar IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=theBox}" x:Name="Calender" Loaded="CalendarLoaded" />
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

When I toggle the checkbox all BlackoutDates remain.

Comment: You are right, that works.. I have a style applied, I wonder if that is somehow messing up when it comes out of disabled?

Comment: That's possible, I guess. Can you try without the style? Do the BlackoutDates disappear when disabling or when enabling?

Comment: After you pointed out it wasnt the calendar control I realised that my blackout day style and my enabled style tried to modify the same visible layer which obviously messes up sometimes, so I added a new containing layer to fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you set large `BlackoutDates` (from `DateTime.MinValue` to almost current dateTime), calendar ovveride `DisplayDateStart`. So, you nedd just set `DisplayDateStart` to value, you need (for example `DateTime.MinValue`)